# How to setup filezilla client to access TOR?

Tags: configuration, proxy, settings

So the question is obvious now here's what I did:
I've tried without openning TOR browser to go to Edit->Settings, then I went to Connection->Generic Proxy and I've selected SOCKS5, then I typed host for 127.0.0.1 and port for 9050 and here's what I've got:

> Status:   Connecting to zx4h3vvf2g2x6rci.onion through SOCKS5 proxy
>   Status:   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9050...
>   Status:   Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
>   Error: Could not connect to server

So I've tried with TOR browser on and same result, I've checked everything and everything is correct. Oh and this is what I get when I try proxy port 9150 with TOR browser on:

> Status:   Connecting to zx4h3vvf2g2x6rci.onion through SOCKS5 proxy
>   Status:   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9150...
>   Status:   Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
>   Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>   Status:   Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
>   Status:   Logged in
>   Status:   Retrieving directory listing...
>   Status:   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9150...
>   Status:   Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
>   Error:    Proxy request failed. Reply from proxy: General SOCKS server failure
>   Error:    Proxy handshake failed: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
>   Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
>   Response: 550-Data channel timed out.
>   Response:  Win32 error:   The network connection was aborted by the local system.
>   Response:  Error details: Data channel timed out.
>   Response: 550 End
>   Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing

With the TOR browser off I get the same result as before with ECONNREFUSED after the second stage of connecting.
So here's what I ask, how to setup filezilla to use with TOR? What am I doing wrong? What software do I need? etc. etc.

So please help me if you can, I've been googling with no luck so I took my last resort is to ask for help :/

Sorry if I can't put direct tags in, I couldn't find any with FTP or filezilla and to create new tags I must have high reputation so sorry for that. I couldn't find any question regarding my problem so I posted a new thread instead. If it was answered please show me the link to the solution and I'll post back to tell you if it helped.

Comment: Try with Orjail: https://github.com/orjail/orjail

Answer (score 0):

A passive FTP setting must be enforced in case of dot-onion FTP servers, because it will use a single TCP pipe opened from your side for both Control and Data streams. Your error log states that data pipe is broken. Active FTP over Tor is possible, but it requires a non-trivial setup on both sides. Use a passive one and be safe :)

Comment: Wrong, that's not how passive FTP works. You've clearly never actually done this or know how FTP works.

Comment: actually, I did. The asker's log is telling that the client has used an active mode where another point-to-point pipe is involved. To solve this there're actually two methods. First - and easiest - is to enforce passive FTP, second - set up *on a server side* a port range for active FTP, add these ports in hidden service's description in Tor config - and then use an active FTP mode in an altered way when the client specifies it's own pre-set-up hidden service, but it's not working 100% with all the clients and servers. Passive FTP is fail-safe in this case and very simple to set up

Comment: @cacahuatl read here, dude :) http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html and after that read how the hidden services are working

Comment: It...doesn't...work. You've clearly never tried this. Passive FTP works on Tor to non-onions, it cannot work to onions without changing the client *and* server to both *not be using the FTP protocol anymore*.

Comment: well, just as a proof-of-concept - do you want me to make a setup that *will* work through Tor? I've made my answer because I've *actually* did it